# How to unwrap Optional<T> type in Swashbuckle

Tags: c#, swashbuckle

My API has a request like

```
public class UserDetailsUpdateRequest
{
    public Optional<string> Name { get; set }
    public Optional<int> Age { get; set; }
}
```

Optional usually wraps a well-known type that Swashbuckle can easily handle if the Optional<> is not there. I know I can configure custom type mappings using SchemaGeneratorOptions.CustomTypeMappings but it requires creating a mapping even for simple types like `string` just because it is wrapped inside an Optional<>.

Is it possible to configure Swashbuckle to automatically unwrap Optional<> and treat the underlying type as it would normally?

I tried the following code:

```
options.UseAllOfForInheritance = true;
            options.SubTypesSelector = type =>
            {
                if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Optional<>))
                {
                    var genericArguments = type.GetGenericArguments();
                    return genericArguments;
                }
            
                return Array.Empty<Type>();
            };
```

I could not find any documentation but based on the method names it sounds like what I need. Unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: There's no `Optional` in .NET or C#. Where does that type come from? Why not use `string?` or `int?` which .NET and Swashbuckle understand?

Comment: Swashbuckle is used to generate OpenAPI specs from classes. This isn't a matter of unwrapping a generic type. You need to write a custom conversion that tells SwashBuckle that `Optional<T>` maps to an optional T specification in OpenAPI.

Comment: Optional<T> is my own custom type. It allows me to have 3 possible values:
1. no value at all
2. null
3. some value